# Feynman diagrams in configuration or momentum space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

Some QFT textbooks (for example Mandl-Shaw at page 113, but also Greiner and others) refer to Feynman diagrams in coordinate space or momentum space. What is exactly the difference between the two types?

Comment: I've not looked at Mandl-Shaw or Greiner but surely they explain this there? What about their explanations is confusing to you? If you don't say this it's impossible to know how to explain in a way that won't be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of correlation functions. Position space correlation functions, like

$$
\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \phi(x_3) \phi(x_4) \rangle
$$

and momentum space correlation functions, like

$$
\langle \tilde{\phi}(k_1) \tilde{\phi}(k_2) \tilde{\phi}(-k_3) \tilde{\phi}(-k_4) \rangle.
$$

The latter is literally just a Fourier transformation of the Former, i.e. you plug in

$$
\int d^4 k_1 d^4 k_2 d^4 k_3 d^4 k_4 e^{-ik_1 x_1} e^{-ik_2 x_2} e^{ik_3 x_3} e^{ik_4 x_4} (\ldots)
$$

The position space correlation functions and momentum space correlation functions each have different Feynman rules to compute them. In most cases, you are far more interested in the momentum space correlation functions than the position space correlation functions. This is because, using the LSZ reduction formula, they are related to scattering amplitudes, and $k_i$ label the momenta of the incoming/outgoing particles.